# Powershell Office 365 Convert users in txt file to shared mailboxes and remove licenses

Tags: powershell, office365

So I have a powershell script that connects me to office 365. This is just standard of the Microsoft website.

I can run either of these commands to remove licenses and convert to shared mailbox's from powershell.

```
Get-Mailbox -identity engineering@domainname.com | set-mailbox -type   “Shared”

$MSOLSKU = (Get-MSOLUser -UserPrincipalName engineering@domainname.com).Licenses[0].AccountSkuId
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName engineering@domainname.com -RemoveLicenses $MSOLSKU
```

I've tried using get-content to get the users from a txt file but can't seem to go from there. Any advice would be highly appreciated and a huge thanks in advance.

Thanks,

SG

Comment: You are asking about how to use a foreach-object or foreach loop then? This could be considered straightforward. Instead of just closing this question can you show us what you have tried to we can potentially explain what went wrong

Comment: I tried this for the first one:
ForEach ($user in (get-content "c:\test\users.txt")) {
Get-Mailbox -identity $user | set-mailbox -type   “Shared”
}